# No output with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

i have a problem with this ng-repeat statement.

```
<div ng-repeat="m in mbct.messages track by $index" ng-click="mbct.message_click($index)" ng-class="mbct.set_class(m.gelesen)">
        <div>ABS: <span ng-bind="m.abs"></span> </div>
        <div>Betreff: <span ng-bind="m.betreff"></span> </div>
        <div>Wann: <span ng-bind="m.timestamp"></span> </div>
        <hr>
    </div>
```

Controller:

```
var self = this;

self.messages = [];
self.massages_length = "";

//initialize variables when app starts
self.init = function(){
    alert("Init-runs");
    MessageService.get_messanges().then(
        function(response){
            self.messages = response.data;
            self.messages_length = self.messages.length;
            console.log(self.messages_length);
        }
    )
};

self.get_message_loop = $interval(function(){
    MessageService.get_messanges().then(
        function(response) {
            if(self.messages_length < response.data.length){
                console.log("new message");
                self.messages = response.data;
                self.messages_length = self.messages.length;
                console.log("self.messages_length:" + self.messages_length);
            }
            else{
                console.log("no new message");
            }
        }
    );
},500);
```

And my Service:

```
gsgmain.factory('MessageService',['$http',function($http){
return{
    get_messanges : function(){
        var email = $("#php_username").html();
    var data = {user_email: email, methode: "get_all_msg"};
    var json_data = angular.toJson(data);
    return $http.post("php/server.php", json_data);
},
    send_message : function(abs,emp,message_text,betreff){
        var data = {abs:abs, emp: emp, message: message_text,betreff:betreff,methode:"send_message"};
        var json_data = angular.toJson(data);
        return $http.post("php/server.php",json_data);
    },
    set_read: function(msg_id){
        var data = {msg_id: msg_id,methode: "set_read"};
        var json_data = angular.toJson(data);
        return $http.post("php/server.php",json_data);
    }
}
}]);
```

The ng-repeat-statement has no output, since i added the if-else-statement in "get_message_loop" to check if there are new messages.
Before the get_message_loop function looked like this:

```
self.get_message_loop = $interval(function(){
    MessageService.get_messanges().then(
        function(response) {
            self.messages = response.data;
        }
    );
},500);
```

and erverything works fine.

Could you tell me why?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

me again :D,

I solved the Problem. I defined the controller twice. One time in the html-tag and the other time in my routeprovider. So the code did everything twice.

And always in the second run, the variable self.messages_length was undefined.

I removed one definition and now everything works fine ;)